# How is the while loop condition re-evaluated again

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I've came across the below code snippet

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag = scan.hasNext();
        while(flag){
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

The boolean flag once assigned the value true or false should not be changed again, but I see that whenever I type something in the terminal the while loop is executed again.

Can someone please explain how the flag is re-evaluated again whenever I type something in the terminal?

**Note: My question is not about stopping/closing the Scanner, but its about understanding how the loop condition is re-evaluated.**

Comment: You need to put `boolean flag = scan.hasNext(); scan.nextLine();` after the boolean

Comment: *Can someone please explain how the flag is re-evaluated*: it's always evaluated to the same value, which is precisely the problem, since you assign a value to `flag` once, and never again. I.e. `scan.hasNext()` is evaluated only once.

Comment: @JBNizet in that case why is while loop not going in infinite loop if the flag is set true for the first time

Comment: @Vivek I am pretty sure it does. How did you determine that it does not go into an infinite loop?

Comment: @Turing85 you are right, I was confused because I didn't knew that nextLine also blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are experiencing here is `scan.hasNext()` blocking until your first input.

Then, the flag is always true.

Once in the loop, you print the next line, but `scan.nextLine()` also blocks until you provide an `EOL`, i.e., an input with a line end.